# Activating screen cast by Intent

Tags: android, google-cast

Is there an `Intent` that will activate the screen mirror function of the `Google Cast` App?

I require the use of this function, and I would like to make its activation as streamlined as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the user has to activate the feature. If you want to mirror your own apps content to a Cast device, then use the Google Cast Remote Display API.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in developing a Remote Display app for screen mirroring, there is a library, [castscreen](https://github.com/ankyl/castscreen), which reduces the process to a few lines of code.

Unfortunately, there's no way to make the process as streamlined as the Google Cast app: they use the `READ_FRAME_BUFFER` manifest permission to get the user's screen contents, whereas third-party apps have to explicitly ask the user for screen capture permission (for clear security reasons). You can use `READ_FRAME_BUFFER` if you ship your own ROM signed with the same private key as the application, though that is impractical for most use cases.

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple method for implementing mirror casting (not google casting).

```
try {
        startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS"));
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.samsung.wfd.LAUNCH_WFD_PICKER_DLG"));
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.CAST_SETTINGS"));
            } catch (Exception e3) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

with these permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```